# "Calculations" of 6-digit octals in 8's complement, in layman's terms?

Tags: math, octal

How does one find the postive/negative range of a 6-digit octal in 8's complement? From what I understand, it's simply half - 1:

`000001 - 377777 positives, 400000 - 77777 negatives`

Would 377777 be the highest positive, and 777777 the highest negative number?

If that is correct, it seems to me that 377777 and 777777 are complements of each other. However, from what I've read, to find the complement, subtract the number from the base. Doing that, 377777 would equal:

`7 - 3 = 4`

`7 - 7 = 0`

`7 - 7 = 0`

`7 - 7 = 0`

`7 - 7 = 0`

`7 - 7 = 0`

`= 400000`

This shows 400000 is the complement of 37777 (which appears inverse to me).

Comment: 77777 is -1, which is the highest negative number (but not with largest magnitude.)

Comment: It's not symmetric. -377777 is 400001. 400000 is the lowest number which has no positive counterpart. -400000 is an invalid operation within these constraints. And 000000 is *not* positive.

Comment: Works the same as with [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Making_the_two.27s_complement_of_a_number). For a complement, subtract each digit 7 as you have done, but _then add 1_. Since 400000 is the lowest value, it is a special case that has no complement that can be represented in six octal digits without overflow.